# UITableViewRowAction completion after animation

Tags: swift, animation, uitableviewrowaction

In my table, I have an `UITableViewRowAction` for `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. When I press it, it will delete all the data in my array, resulting in triggering the `didSet` on the array ending with the view changing. The code looks as follows:

```
var data: [Int] = [Int]() {
    didSet {
        if data.isEmpty {
            // change view
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var confirm = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Confirm") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        self.data.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }
    return [confirm]
}
```

What I'd like to get is some kind of completion after the animation of the `UITableViewRowAction` is finished (row moving back in it's place), then empty the array and changing the views. If possible I'd like to avoid using a manual delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var data: [Int] = [Int]() {
    didSet {
        if data.isEmpty {
            // change view
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var confirm = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Confirm") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            self.data.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        })
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    return [confirm]
}
```

The code in `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({/* completion code */})` is run after the other code between `CATransaction.begin()` and `CATransaction.commit()` finishes getting executed. So here `self.data.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` should get called after `self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` is finished animating.

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I have not tested this code myself with `tableView.setEditing(...)`, but I have used it for `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(...)`.